# Will exists clause compare the records?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables as

```
tb1(field1 int) containing 1,2,3,4
tb2(field2 int) containing 4,12,19,30
```

When I run

```
select * from tb1 where exists(select * from tb2 );
```

I'm getting the entire values from tb1. Why it's so? I thought that the it will bring only 4 as it is present in both tables. Now I'm totally confused with the exists clause. I want to know what the exists clause is doing here ? Please help me.

Comment: Because "SELECT * FROM tb2" exists

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
exists(select * from tb2 )
```

is not correlated to the outer query. It can be evaluated completely independently of it. It will evaluate to `true` if the table `tb2` contains any rows and false if the table is empty. As `tb2` does contain at least one row it is evaluated as true and so your `where` clause evaluates to `true` for every row.

You need to correlate it so it works as you desire

```
SELECT *
FROM   tb1
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT *
              FROM   tb2
              WHERE  tb1.field1 = tb2.field2);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Bur I have a doubt. The where clause in the inner query i.e tb1.field1 = tb2.field2 will produce 4. Now the exists clause evaluates to true. Then why the outer query didn't show the entire table since the exists clause evaluates to true ? Please explain me.

Comment: @nukes Because the where clause is evaluated for each row. It is only true for that row.

Comment: So u mean that it checks weather the records in the outer query exists in the relation produced by the inner query.Then why it is not checking when the where clause is not provided in the inner query ?